# Detect if url represents streaming link

Tags: python-requests, http-headers, streaming, python-3.7

I am trying to indicate if a URL contains streaming.
I want to close the connection if the link is a streaming link.

1. Is there a better way to check if the link is a streaming link?
2. Can I do the request without using `stream=True`? Because I am only interested in `content-Type:'text/*'`

What did I try:
I tried to send the header `Connection: close` but it didn't stop the stream.
I also tried to send the header `Connection: Keep-Alive` and `Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1` didn't do the job.
I tried to pass `stream=False` but I couldn't receive `request.text`.

My attempt:

```
def ignore_stream():
    with requests.get('https://google.com', timeout=5, stream=True) as r:
        if 'Content-Type' in r.headers:
            if 'audio' in r.headers['Content-Type'] or 'video' in r.headers['Content-Type']:
                print(r.headers['Content-Type'])
                print('streaming link .. close the connection')
                r.close()
            else:
                print('text page .. get text content')
                print(r.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ignore_stream()
```

The code above does close the stream connection, but I am afraid, that won't be enough for stream detection.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection gets closed because of that `with` statement, as it is calling `Response.close()` automatically at the end of the statement. There is no need to do `r.close()`, just leave the statement do the job or remove it and do it yourself.

Sending the request with the `stream` flag as `True` will only download the response headers at first (more info [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow)). This means that if you only want the `text/**` responses (and mark the rest as "streaming" URLs), you can achieve it at this point. See the demo below and let me know if it suits you:

```py
# using "with" statement
def ignore_stream_with():
    with requests.get('https://google.com', timeout=5, stream=True) as r:
        if 'Content-Type' in r.headers:
            if 'audio' in r.headers['Content-Type'] or 'video' in r.headers['Content-Type']:
                print(r.headers['Content-Type'])
                print('Link detected as streaming... Leaving "with" to close the connection.')
            else:
                print('Link detected as text!')
                print('Response content:')
                print(r.text)

                # do more stuff with your response...
                pass

# NOT using "with" statement
def ignore_stream_without():
    r = requests.get('https://google.com', timeout=5, stream=True)

    if 'Content-Type' in r.headers:
        if 'audio' in r.headers['Content-Type'] or 'video' in r.headers['Content-Type']:
            print(r.headers['Content-Type'])
            print('Link detected as streaming... Leaving "with" to close the connection.')
        else:
            print('Link detected as text!')
            print('Response content:')
            print(r.text)

            # do more stuff with your response...
            pass

    # remember always to close the connection!
    r.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ignore_stream()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a good point about the 'with' statement. My main question was if there is a better method indicating that I am requesting a streaming link and why connection: close or keep alive with max and timeout parameters didn't work.

Comment: The "streaming" property of a connection is the `Transfer-encoding` of that connection. If it has the value `chunked`, it means that the payload is divided into various chunks that come in order. You have more info in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding

Comment: And about the `connection.close` and `Keep-Alive` header... What do you mean with "didn't work"? Did it prompt an error when you ran it?

Comment: Those headers didn't close the streaming flow, hence, the connection carried on.